# What is a String Wall?

Tags: particle-physics, beyond-the-standard-model, cosmic-string, topological-defects

This question has nothing to do with sound waves, physical strings or walls...

I am reading: https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.07091

It states

> "In the post-inflationary PQ symmetry breaking scenario, axions can be produced from the decay of string-wall systems, and we must take account of such contributions quantitatively."

I am not sure what they mean by decay of a string wall system.

Can someone please explain this?

Comment: A network of "topological defects": 1-dimensional (cosmic string), 2-dimensional (domain wall). Lines attached to planes, with the lines and planes being places where the ground state of the quantum fields is different. I hope someone will give a proper answer.

Comment: Throw a string of cooked spaghetti on the backsplash.  If it sticks, you know it's done.  Douse in cold water immediately, so that it is slightly al dente.

Answer (score 1):

From the same paper:

> Since the axion fieldamust vary from $0$ to $2πv_{PQ}$ around the core of the string, strings are always attached by $N_{DW}$ domain walls. The subsequent evolution of such string-wall systems isdifferent according to the value of $N_{DW}$, which is determined from the QCD anomaly coefficientand hence depends on underlying particle physics models

So, "string-wall systems" are essentially formed by one or more domain walls attached to a cosmic string.

(Or is the question what are cosmic strings and domain walls?)

Comment: I understand the cosmic string theory.  ( hypothetical 1-dimensional topological defects which may have formed during a symmetry breaking phase transition in the early universe ) - what I do not understand is the domain wall part.